# Não é possível localizar a coluna 22276451.

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

Bom dia, estou a desenvolver um código que possa deferir os valores X e Y  de um chart que inseri em asp.net. Para tal fiz uma query ao sql server para que me fosse retornada a media de uma coluna, ate que surgiu o seguinte erro :  Não é possível localizar a coluna 22276451. 
Preciso da vossa colaboração para resolver este problema.

Aqui segue o código:

```
 protected void Chart1_Load6(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        String connectionString =
       "Data Source=localhost;" +
       "Initial Catalog=DB_SACC;" +
       "User id=sa;" +
       "Password=1234;";

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        string textt = "  SELECT AVG (Total_Divida) FROM t_pagamentos";

        cmd.CommandText = textt;

        connection.Open();

        cmd.Connection = connection;

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        decimal average = (decimal)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "Banco";

        Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember =Convert.ToString( average);
  }
```

Comment: Será necessário mais informações, adiciona por favor a estrutura/script de criação da tabela t_pagamentos.

Comment: a estrutura foi criada no sql nao é relevante para o caso , mas talvez seja relevante informar que este código esta associado a um chart com um ligação a minha base de dados talvez seja esse  o problema .

Comment: "Não é possível localizar a coluna 22276451", a estrutura para não estar adequada ao select efectuado...

Comment: Pedro eu testei a query na base de dados em sql e esta funcional

Comment: Ok, se a componente sql está funcional, deverá o Chart1.Series, mostra a componente onde adicionas a Serie,
Chart1.Series.Add("Series1"); isto existe?

Comment: esta no código em que eu pus na pergunta inicial . Esse é o codigo que estou  a  usar.

Comment: Sim, mas para no Chart1 teres uma série com o nome "Series1" precisas do comando que mencionei, e no código acima não vejo nenhuma inicialização.

Comment: será que me podias dar um exemplo pratico ? agradecido!